# How to compute f1 in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, accuracy, metric, f1score

I have a code that computes the accuracy, but now I would like to compute the F1 score.

```
accuracy_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
    tf.argmax(output_1, axis=-1),
    tf.argmax(y_1, axis=-1)), tf.float32), name="accuracy_1")
accuracy_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
    tf.argmax(output_2, axis=-1),
    tf.argmax(y_2, axis=-1)), tf.float32), name="accuracy_2")
```

How can I compute F1 equivalent for the above code? I'm finding it difficult as I am very new to TensorFlow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tf 2.0+:

```
f1 = 2*(tf.compat.v1.metrics.recall(labels, predictions) * tf.compat.v1.metrics.precision(labels, predictions)) / ( tf.compat.v1.metrics.recall(labels, predictions) + tf.compat.v1.metrics.precision(labels, predictions))
```

In previous versions you can use the contrib.metrics submodule (deprecated in 1.14):

```
tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(labels, predictions)
```

Answer (score 4):

TF Addons computes the [F1 score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score) and more generally the [FBeta Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/FBetaScore)

Comment: Alas, TF Addons is deprecated and will be End-of-Life'd in May 2024.  
Keras is supposed to support it but its currently only available in the nightly-builds at this time: `tf.keras.metrics.F1Score` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/F1Score)).

Answer (score 1):

To compute `f1_score`, first, use this function of python [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) library to produce confusion matrix. After that, from the confusion matrix, generate `TP`, `TN`, `FP`, `FN` and then use them to calculate:

`Recall = TP/TP+FN`  and  `Precision = TP/TP+FP`

And then from the above two metrics, you can easily calculate:

`f1_score = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)`

OR

you can use another function of the same library [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) to compute `f1_score` directly from the generated `y_true` and `y_pred` like below:

```
F1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average = 'binary')
```

Finally, the library links consist of a helpful explanation. You should read them carefully.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I know how to compute f1, but i want it in tensorflow, i basically want to replace the above code mentioned with f1.

Comment: tensorflow has a tf.metrics function, see here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics

Comment: i saw that, but it doesnt' seem to work. That's the reason i posted here.

Answer (score 0):

F1 score can be defined as a custom metric. Keras will evaluate this metric on each batch/epoch as applicable.

```
import keras.backend as K

def f1_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_val = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon())
    return f1_val
    
    
model.compile(...,metrics=['accuracy', f1_metric])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I know how to do this in keras, but i want it in tensorflow, i basically want to replace the above code mentioned with f1.

Comment: TF has builtin metric for F1 . https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/f1_score

Comment: i saw that, but it doesnt seem to work. That's the reason i posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Keras is in early stages of supporting the [F1Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/F1Score) and [FBetaScore](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/FBetaScore) score, but it currently only in nightly-builds. Example from the docs:

```
metric = tf.keras.metrics.FBetaScore(beta=2.0, threshold=0.5)
y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0]], np.int32)
y_pred = np.array([[0.2, 0.6, 0.7],
                   [0.2, 0.6, 0.6],
                   [0.6, 0.8, 0.0]], np.float32)
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
result = metric.result()
result.numpy()
```